# DateCreated nulled out when editing

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am trying my hand at ef code first and running into issues.

I have a interface IAuditable:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

I have my model:

```
public class Tip : IAuditable
{
    public int TipId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Posted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

And then in my DbContext I have overridden SaveChanges to save the correct values to these fields:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DateTime auditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

    foreach (DbEntityEntry<IAuditable> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.Entity.DateCreated = auditDate;
            entry.Entity.DateModified = auditDate;
        }
        else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entry.Entity.DateModified = auditDate;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Creation of the item works as expected. DateCreated and DateModified are set. However, on edit it sets the DateModified but nulls out my DateCreated field. What's going on?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Most likely the problem is not in your `SaveChanges` but in your application code that marks the entity as modified. Probably the `DateCreated` is `null` there and the property is marked as modified, so EF just saves that `null` to the DB. Typical example in a web app is that you only *display* the `DateCreated` in your Edit view. After post back the property is `null` (because it has no form field), then you set the entity state to `Modifed` and you have the `null` in the DB. (Simplest solution: Add a hidden form field for `DateCreated` to your view.)

Comment: Have you considered setting the datetime values by database triggers? Does not show the cause of your issue, of course. (It would just disappear.) I think it is safer anyway, because the time is set exactly at the right moment. Doing it from client code always causes an unpredictable lag (like when there are very many entries in the ChangeTracker, or for SaveChanges to open the connection).